# How to apply webpack for the angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I am new to angularjs and webpack. I had been working in angularjs with following folder structure:
**app**

- js

  - app.js
  - controller.js
  - service.js
  - directive.js
  - routes.js
  - abc.js
  - xyz.js
- templates

  - home.html
  - faq.html
  - abc.html
  - xyz.html
  - bcd.html
- assets

  - css

    - bootstrap.css
    - style.css
    - abc.css
  - js

    - bootstrap.js
    - tether.js
    - popper.js
    - wow.js
    - jquery.js
    - abc.js
  - img

    - a.jpg
    - b.jpg
  - font

    - as.ttf
- index.html
- package.json
- serve.js

I have searched through multiple tutorials but could not find an example that fits my requirement. Can somebody help me bundle using webpack for bundling js in app, js in assets and css in assets.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: First: do you know what webpack is and what is the philosophy behind? Second: what have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried the basic configuration as found in various tutorials. One from the webpack website as well as other sites. Those tutorial didnot represent the file system that i was using.

Answer (score 0):

with node.js you need just to inizialize the project and install webpack

```
npm init
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

Then you need just configure the webpack.config.js file.
I suggest you to read the official documentation

Comment: i have done the steps for webpack install and configured the webpack too. But the bundling process is not done correctly, angular modules are not refrenced properly.